# Python: Setting values to 0 when crops are out of bounds

Tags: python, image, numpy, crop

So I am trying to make a 250x250 crop from an image. I'm cropping it from -125 to 125 for each dimension, thus, it is out of bounds. I'd like to set every value that is out of bounds to 0. Currently, I have the following:

`im_cropped = im[-125:125,-125:125]`

However, this outputs an error as negative indices do not exist. Is there a way to produce a 250x250 crop with all out of bounds pixels set to 0?

Comment: What is the type of `im`? If it is a `numpy` array, then "-125" means "125 elements from the back".

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
cropSize = 250
im_cropped = np.zeros_like(im)
bidx = (np.array(im.shape)-cropSize)/2
eidx = bidx + cropSize
cropSlice = np.s_[bidx[0]:eidx[0],bidx[1]:eidx[1]]
im_cropped[cropSlice] = im[cropSlice]
```

I think this will do what you're looking for. It creates an array of all zeros and then copies the middle 250x250 square from the original image. The np.s_[] trick creates a slice object that you can use with multiple arrays without having to rewrite the slice.